# Unitys [SerializeField] and parallel inheritance

Tags: unity, serialization, inheritance

I have the following:

```
public class Item
{
    [SerializeField]ItemData _data;

    public ItemData data { get { return _data; } }
}

public class Weapon : Item
{
    [SerializeField]WeaponData _data;

    public WeaponData data { get { return _data; } }
}

public class ItemData : ScriptableObject { }
public class WeaponData : ItemData { }
```

It seems like a pretty common setup to me, data is separated from logic classes - and I can use single scriptable objects to define stats for alot of items.

However, Unity gives me this error message:

> The same field name is serialized multiple times in the class or its
>   parent class. This is not supported:

I understand what's going wrong, but I don't get how to work around it, I want the data objects to inherit so I don't need to keep two (or more, further into inheritance) separate data objects per weapon.

I also need the item inheritance for inventory/merchant list management.
Using hiding screws up the serialization of the baseclass, which means I can't create default items - not feasible.

The issue is the same when using public instead of [SerializeField].

Any pointers?

Comment: My immediate thought is "if you need to do this, you're almost certainly doing something wrong." e.g. if I have a `Weapon` object instanced, called `weap` and I do `weap.data`, what should I get back? An `ItemData` or a `WeaponData`?

Comment: You are on the right track(logic-wise), but looking at the code I think some misunderstanding of inheritance concept is taking place. Serialization message just misleads you from the real problem(redeclaration of the same field in derived class?). I strongly advice looking at Unity provided example of inheritance, this might help https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/inheritance

Comment: Whether or not this is the right approach, usually serialization issues like this stem from the variable name itself. Typically auto serialization generates a getter and setter based on the variable name. Just like in a class you cant have two variables with the same name in the same scope, the same applies to inheritance without override.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you might actually want an `IItem` interface, or abstract class, a bit like this:

```
// Establish the contract that any "Item-ish"
// object must be able to provide ItemData
// through a standard property (could be abstract
// instead of an interface if you have code or
// members you want to share between item types.
public interface IItem
{
   public ItemData data { get; };
}

public class Item : IItem
{
    // Expose an inspector field of the concrete
    // type we want - this will accept ItemData
    // or any type inheriting from it.
    [SerializeField] ItemData _data;

    // Return this inspector-set property as our
    // IItem-mandated data property  
    public ItemData data { get {return _data; } }
}

public class Weapon : IItem
{
    // Expose an inspector field of the concrete
    // type we want - this will accept only WeaponData
    // not ItemData instances that aren't weapon-specific.
    [SerializeField] WeaponData _data;

    // Return this specialized WeaponData as an ItemData
    // when requested.
    public ItemData data { get {return _data; } }
}
```

Now any code can work with a mixed group of Items and Weapons by treating them all as items. It can also use casts or the `as` keyword to get at Weapon/item-type-specific data when it knows it has a particular item type.

If you go much further with this, you may want to consider applying the principle of [Composition Over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Especially in Unity's setup, this can give you a lot more flexibility - letting you make things like a spiked shield that has both a DefensiveItem component and a WeaponItemComponent, without needing to refactor two separate branches of the inheritance hierarchy to handle such exceptions and hybrids.